# prove a long trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that if $0 < \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta\in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 < \pi, \beta + \alpha_1 < \pi$, then $$\sin \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}2 \sin \frac{\beta}2 \sin (\pi/2 - \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \beta}2) + \sin(\pi/2 - \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}2)\sin \frac{\alpha_1}2 \sin \frac{\alpha_2}2 = \sin \frac{\alpha_1 + \beta}2 \sin \frac{\alpha_2}2 \sin (\pi/2 - \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \beta}2) + \sin (\pi/2 - \frac{\alpha_1 + \beta}2) \sin\frac{\alpha_1}2 \sin\frac{\beta}2$$.

I was thinking of using the angle addition identity for sine and cosine as well as the following product-to-sum formulas:

$\cos x + \cos y = 2\cos \frac{x+y}2 \cos \frac{x-y}2, \cos y - \cos x = 2\sin \frac{x+y}2 \sin \frac{x-y}2, \sin x + \sin y = 2\sin \frac{x+y}2 \cos \frac{x-y}2, \sin x - \sin y = 2\sin\frac{x-y}2 \cos \frac{x+y}2$,

which hold for all real numbers $x,y$. The formulas could be used to show that

$$\cos \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \beta}2 (\cos \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - \beta}2 - \cos \frac{\alpha_1 - \alpha_2 + \beta}2) = \sin \frac{\alpha_1}2 (\sin (\beta + \frac{\alpha_1}2) - \sin(\alpha_2 + \frac{\alpha_1}2)),$$

but I'm not sure how to apply them to prove the original identity.

Comment: Is the last term definitely meant to have $\alpha_1$ twice but no $\alpha_2$?

Comment: @J.G. thanks for catching that typo.

Comment: But my question still applies to the _new_ last term.

Comment: *Mathematica* confirms that the identity holds without conditions on the angles. BTW, you can eliminate a lot of visual clutter by defining, say, $p:=\alpha_1/2$, $q:=\alpha_2/2$, $r:=\beta/2$, and by invoking $\sin(\pi/2-x)=\cos x$, to write
$$\phantom{=}\sin(p+q)\sin r\cos(p+q+r)+\cos(p+q)\sin p\sin q \\
= \sin(p+r)\sin q\cos(p+q+r)+\cos(p+r)\sin p\sin r$$ From here, I don't see a particularly clever way to proceed. (Does the context of the problem suggest that there should be one?) I would probably gather the two $\cos(p+q+r)$ terms together, and the two $\sin p$ terms, and go from there.